# Does exist any free dataset (geocoded or by country) on UXO?

Tags: data-request

I am looking for a free of charge global or european dataset listing UXO presence or UXO incidents.

Comment: Unexploded ordnance? Please [edit] your question and explain. And your question is missing a lot of info, read [this](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some sources.

Zetica supplies risk maps for free for the UK.

https://zeticauxo.com/downloads-and-resources/risk-maps/

OrdTek and EMODnet have water mine maps for a few European countries.

http://www.ordtek.com/mine-map/

http://www.emodnet-humanactivities.eu/view-data.php

Propublica has performed a freedom of information request to get data that includes discarded munitions and explosives, which is available for download.

https://www.propublica.org/datastore/dataset/defense-environmental-restoration-program-military-cleanup-sites

Australia has a UXO map.

http://www.defence.gov.au/UXO/Where/Default.asp